# BZIP2 linking error with Cygwin64

Tags: cygwin, bzip2

I encounter the following linking error when attempting to use  in Cygwin64. My PATH accounts for the location of libbz2.a and libbz2.dll.

```
$ gcc -lbz2 bzlibExample.c -o bzlibExample
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzWriteOpen'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x18b): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `BZ2_bzWriteOpen'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x1ef): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzWrite'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x1ef): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `BZ2_bzWrite'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x233): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzWriteClose'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x233): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `BZ2_bzWriteClose'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `BZ2_bzWriteClose'
/tmp/ccz9P7fm.o:bzlibExample.c:(.text+0x2bb): relocation truncated to fit: R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `BZ2_bzWriteClose'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: try `gcc  bzlibExample.c -o bzlibExample -lbz2`

Comment: IT WORKED! - thank you sir!